# Solving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2015^{k}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2015^i\sum_{l=0}^k2015^l}=$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2015^{k}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2015^i\sum_{l=0}^k2015^l}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2015^k}{\frac{1-2015^k}{1-2015}\cdot\frac{1-2015^{k+1}}{1-2015}}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2015^k}{\frac{1-2015^{k+1}-2015^k+2015^{2k+1}}{2014^2}}$$
I'm not sure what to do next, I'm stuck there. Any tips?

**Edit:** Just to save for later.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}2014^2\bigg(\frac{1}{2014}\cdot\bigg(\frac{1}{2015^k-1}-\frac{1}{2015^{k+1}-1}\bigg)\bigg)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2014\frac{2015(2015^n-1)}{2014(2015^{n+1}-1)}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2015(2015^n-1)}{2015^{n+1}-1}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2015^{n+1}-2015}{2015^{n+1}-1}\bigg/\frac{:2015^{n+1}}{:2015^{n+1}}=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{1}{2015^n}}{1-\frac{1}{2015^{n+1}}}=1$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More general, $\frac{x^k}{(1-x^{k})(1-x^{k+1})}=\frac{1}{x-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^k-1}-\frac{1}{x^{k+1}-1}\right)$.

Thus

$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{(1-x^{k})(1-x^{k+1})}&=&\frac{1}{x-1}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{x^k-1}-\frac{1}{x^{k+1}-1}\right)=\frac{x(x^n-1)}{(x-1)^2(x^{n+1}-1)}
\end{eqnarray}$

Therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x^k}{\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}}=(1-x)^2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{(1-x^k)\cdot(1-x^{k+1})}=\frac{x(x^n-1)}{x^{n+1}-1}$$

Can you continue?

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: In the end, I got the limit is 1, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. Indeed, it is for all $|x|>1$